# Probability Function Proof: Since $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c$, then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$

Tags: probability

I am reading *Statistical Theory: A Concise Introduction*, by Felix Abramovich and Ya'acov Ritov. In the the appendix, the authors provide a primer on basic probability theory. In discussing the probability function, the authors write the following:

> The probability function assigns to each event $A \in \mathcal{A}$ a real number $P(A)$ called the *probability* of $A$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> ...
>
> 5. Since $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c$, then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$.

Note that $A$ denotes an event.

Intuitively, I can tell that the proposition is true. However, I wanted to prove it in my notes. I unsuccessfully attempted to do this by using De Morgan's laws and the fact that $P(A^c) = 1 - P(A) \ \forall \ A$.

I was wondering if people could please take the time to show me the correct proof for this.

EDIT:

It seems to me that we have an if/then statement of the form, "Since (**If**) $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c$, then $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$.

A (Hypothesis): $(A_1 \cup A_2)^c = A_1^c \cap A_2^c$.

B (Conclusion): $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$.

So for a proof, we need to either work forwards from A to B or backwards from B to A.

Comment: Your approach using DeMorgan's Law together with the complementarity theorem (or occasionally axiom) should do it.

Comment: The flip side of De Morgan's laws is $(A_1 \cap A_2)^c=A_1^c \cup A_2^c$.

Comment: Does anyone want to post a complete proof? Or at least something useful/insightful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $(A_{1}\cup A_{2})^{c}=A_{1}^{c}\cap A_{2}^{c}.$ We want to find an expression for $P(A_{1}\cap A_{2})$. Since the probability of an event is equal to one minus the probability of the complement of the event, we have
$$P(A_{1}\cap A_{2})=1-P((A_{1}\cap A_{2})^{c}).\tag{1}\label{1}$$
From the assumption,
$$(A_{1}^{c}\cup A_{2}^{c})^{c}=(A_{1}^{c})^{c}\cap (A_{2}^{c})^{c}.$$
Since the double complement of a set is equal to the original set, this is
$$(A_{1}^{c}\cup A_{2}^{c})^{c}=A_{1}\cap A_{2}.$$
Plugging this expression into $\eqref{1},$ we get
$$P(A_{1}\cap A_{2})=1-P(((A_{1}^{c}\cup A_{2}^{c})^{c})^{c}).$$
Finally, to simplify the expression on the right-hand side, we once again use the fact that the double complement of a set is equal to the original set. We obtain
$$P(A_{1}\cap A_{2})=1-P(A_{1}^{c}\cup A_{2}^{c}),$$
as desired.

Comment: This is what I was seeking. Thank you for the clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because, as stated, $(A_1\cup A_2)^\complement=A_1^\complement\cap A_2^\complement$, therefore they will have the same probability measure:$$\color{red}{\mathsf P((A_1\cup A_2)^\complement)}=\color{blue}{\mathsf P(A_1^\complement\cap A_2^\complement)}\tag 1$$

Now, by definition, for any event, $A$, then: $\mathsf P(A)=1-\mathsf P(A^\complement)$, and because $A_1\cup A_2$ is an event, therefore by instantiation: 
$$\mathsf P(A_1\cup A_2)=1-\color{red}{\mathsf P((A_1\cup A_2)^\complement)}\tag 2$$

Substitution will give the required result.
$$\therefore\quad\mathsf P(A_1\cup A_2)=1-\color{blue}{\mathsf P(A_1^\complement\cap A_2^\complement)}\tag 3$$

That is all.

Comment: I don't understand what insight this is meant to provide. These are trivial results -- none of which are the "required result" for a proof.

Comment: It is a trivial result.  There is nothing deeper about it.  $(1)\wedge (2) \implies (3)$.

Comment: But how is this supposed to help me? I already mentioned in the main post that I tried using De Morgan’s laws. The entire reason I asked for assistance was because I tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: @ThePointer $(1)$ is true *because* DeMorgan's Laws for Sets states: $(A_1\cup A_2)^\complement=(A_1^\complement\cap A_2^\complement)$.  How are you being unsuccessful at using this?

Comment: Yes, of course it’s true — it’s the hypothesis. Isn’t the point of a proof to show that the hypothesis implies the conclusion? You’ve shown that A (the hypothesis) is true. But the entire point of a proof is to show that A implies the conclusion, B. See the edit in my main post. I don’t understand why you keep emphasising that the hypothesis is true when that is the case by definition. The goal is to develop a proof.

Comment: *Because* the sets are identical they have the same probability $(1)$.  The definition for probability of complements gives an expression involving one of them $(2)$.  *Because* they have the same probability $(1)$, those probability expressions can be *substituted* for each other in $(2)$, giving the required result $(3)$.  Thus is proven that deMorgan's Law *and* the definition for probability of complements *entails* the result.

Comment: Ok, please specify where in your proof you have concluded that $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 1 - P((A_1 \cap A_2)^c) = 1 - P(A_1^c \cup A_2^c)$? I honestly do not understand how you could tell me that this is a proof when not a single expression from the conclusion is even mentioned in it. You have only mentioned the hypothesis (in (1)) but never the conclusion. You've got high reputation, so I must be completely missing something here. But, for the life of me, I cannot see how this could possibly be a proof.

Comment: You've clearly started correctly with the hypothesis in (1), so where is the conclusion? (2) and (3) do not contain a single expression from the conclusion.